# Used Yeoman to create Angular project w/ Gulp, Protractor not working

Tags: angularjs, selenium, gulp, protractor, yeoman-generator-angular

Subject kind of says it all. Using OSX Yosemite, tried updating webdriver, chromedriver and PhantomJS, getting this error:

```
[15:41:30] Starting 'inject'...
[15:41:30] gulp-inject 1 files into index.html.
[15:41:30] gulp-inject 3 files into index.html.
[15:41:30] Finished 'inject' after 84 ms
[15:41:30] Starting 'serve:e2e'...
[15:41:30] Finished 'serve:e2e' after 17 ms
[15:41:30] Starting 'protractor:src'...
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
    [launcher] Process exited with error code 1
    /Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/async/nexttick.js:39
      goog.global.setTimeout(function() { throw exception; }, 0);
                                            ^
    Error: spawn EACCES
        at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
        at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:1162:11)
        at Object.exports.spawn (child_process.js:995:9)
        at module.exports (/Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js:109:27)
        at /Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:170:21
        at promise.ControlFlow.runInFrame_ (/Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1877:20)
        at promise.Callback_.goog.defineClass.notify (/Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:2464:25)
        at promise.Promise.notify_ (/Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:563:12)
        at Array.forEach (native)
        at Object.goog.array.forEach (/Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/goog/array/array.js:203:43)

    /Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/gulp/e2e-tests.js:23
            throw err;
```

ANY help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
James

**UPDATE:** I added more of the error message above.

Comment: i think it's practically impossible to help without viewing the code

Comment: Do you mean the gulp file or protractor.conf file? I could put the actual code up, this works on a Windows 8.1 box, so I don't think it's the application or test code. Could be wrong through.

Comment: Have you `chown` the project directory?

Comment: It was in my Documents folder already, but I tried it anyway and it had no effect.

Comment: what is the version of node_modules/protractor/selenium/chromedriver (or firefoxdriver, or what are you using?) + what is the version of your browser and selenium ?

Comment: Almost forgot; phantomJS is version 1.9.8 and chromeDriver is version 2.14.313457. Thanks.

Comment: Node - 0.12.2, NPM - 2.7.6, Protractor - 2.0.0, Webdriver manager - 4.0.0. I tried to check the version of Selenium and it looked like is wasn't installed. I installed it using "sudo easy_install selenium" and it looked like it installed version 2.20.0 of selenium and 2.45.1 of selenium-webdriver, but it didn't seem to fix the problem, and I get an error if I try to run selenium manually.

Answer (score 1):

The `Error: spawn EACCES` error means that the file is not executable.  I am assuming that you are on a Mac based on the file path, so something like this should fix your problem:

```
cd /Users/jbender/Documents/Github/PTest/
chmod -R +x *
```

Of course, this probably isn't what you want to do since this will make *all* your files executable. It's probably one of the files in your node_modules directory that needs to be executable. Without more information, I can't tell you which one. You can probably figure that out on your own.

Comment: Thanks. Went ahead and changed them all since this is a test/throw away project to validate my selenium/webdriver/protractor installation. Didn't work, same error. I used Yeoman to create this and (theoretically) it's supposed to chmod the appropriate files as part of the scaffolding process.

Answer (score 0):

Ugh! Ok, turns out my installation of Java was corrupted somehow. I noticed this when I went to start up WebStorm and it complained. Reinstalled and it's fine now. Thanks for the help!